# How can i pause a mp3 file being played in a voice channel discordjs

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: '1am',
    description: "1am song",
    execute(message, args) {

        // Checking if the message author is in a voice channel.
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply("You must be in a voice channel.");
        // Checking if the bot is in a voice channel.
        if (message.guild.me.voice.channel) return message.reply("I'm already playing.");

        // Joining the channel and creating a VoiceConnection.
        message.member.voice.channel.join().then(VoiceConnection => {
            // Playing the music, and, on finish, disconnecting the bot.
            VoiceConnection.play("./music/1am.mp3").on("finish", () => VoiceConnection.disconnect());
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#A79A9A')
                .setTitle('1 A.M Study Session :books: - [lofi hip hop/chill beats]')
                .setDescription('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTRiuFIWV54&t=191s')
            message.channel.send(embed)
        }).catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
}
```

Comment: The StreamDispatcher has a [`pause()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher?scrollTo=pause) function

Comment: how would i add that?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the player to a variable

```
myVar = VoiceConnection.play("./music/1am.mp3").on("finish", () => VoiceConnection.disconnect());
```

And where you want to pause the mp3:

```
myVar.pause()
```

Comment: could you add that to my code im not getting how to do it